# Convert bool to bool? in @Html.CheckBoxFor() call in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to retrieve the `bool` value from the CheckBox and assign it to the variable `m.IsAdministrator`, which is of type `bool?`:

`@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => (bool?)(m.isAdministrator))`

However, this syntax gives an error. How can I assign the `bool` CheckBoxFor return value to a `bool?`?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @RufusL "Cannot cast from `bool?` to `bool`" from the MVC framework when it tries to compile the view, because it expects [`<Expression<Func<TModel,bool>>>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.checkboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.CheckBoxFor%60%601%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper{%60%600},System.Linq.Expressions.Expression{System.Func{%60%600,System.Boolean}}%29) but finds `<Expression<Func<TModel,bool?>>>`.

Comment: To get a `bool` from a `bool?`, where you want the default value to be `false` if the `bool?` is `null`, then you would use the `.Value` property if `.HasValue` is `true`, otherwise use `false`. You can do this with the `?:` ternary operatory:  `bool x = m.isAdministrator.HasValue ? m.isAdministrator.Value : false;`

Comment: @RufusL It will not work with an MVC binding. Please see the duplicate question.

Comment: A `bool?` has 3 states (`true`, `null` and `false`). A checkbox has only 2 therefore you cannot use a checkbox for a `bool?` Either make the property `bool` or use `EditorFor(m =>m.isAdministrator)` which willl generate a dropdownlist with 3 values

Comment: Thanks all for your help. It sounds like @StephenMuecke 's answer is the one that worked. Stephen, if you make that an official answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have duped it. But its Darin Dimitrov's answer which is the correct one in the dupe.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.isAdministrator.Value)
```

And be sure to check that it has value before or you'll get exception.

However, using nullable in view model is not a best practice.

Comment: This binding will compile, but it makes no sense. The value will be `null` on a `POST`.